# filter rows with dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery, filtering

I'm having a heck of a time getting this to work.  Should be simple, but every route I've tried has not worked.  Here's the jQuery I'm using now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //filter list by year
        $(function () {
            $("#ddYear").change(function (evt) {
                var year = $("#ddYear").val();

                $('tr').show();

                $("td[id^='AccessRequestID']").each(function () {
                    alert("Checking " + this.val);
                    if ($(this).attr("class") == ".AR_" + year) {
                        alert("Hiding " + this.val);
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's the table I'm trying to filter:

```
<div class="index-header">Select a Year to View: <%:Html.DropDownList("ddYear", Model.YearList, null %></div>

<table id="arTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Year
        </th>
        <th>
            Version
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>

    </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model.AccessRequests) { %>

        <tr class="clickable">
            <td id="AccessRequestID<%=item.Access_Request_ID%>" class="<%:string.Format("AR_{0}", item.RECORD_YEAR) %>">
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RECORD_YEAR) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VERSION_NO) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMPLOYEE_NAME) %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

</table>
```

I initially tried doing something like this:

```
$("td[id^='AccessRequestID']").parent().hide().filter('.AR_' + year).show();
```

and while that filtered the rows out great, it didn't unfilter them back in when it should have.  So I tried adding `$("td[id^='AccessRequestID']").parent().show;` to reset it first, but that didn't do a thing.  (I also tried it with `.each()`, as you can see in my last try).  Any advice or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/96Evt/
The code is below and I added some demo table rows in the fiddle too.

```
$("#ddYear").on('change', function () {
        var year = $("#ddYear").val();
        $('tr').show();

        $("td.AR").each(function (index, tdAR) {
            if ($(tdAR).hasClass("AR_" + year)) {
                $(tdAR).parent('tr').hide();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Amazing.  That worked...Any idea why the several approaches I tried didn't?  I'm pretty stumped!

Comment: Well actually to clarify, it worked the opposite of what I needed, but I changed 'if ($(tdAR).hasClass("AR_" + year))' to 'if (!$(tdAR).hasClass("AR_" + year))' and it works great

Comment: Glad it's working for you. I think the fact that you had `if ($(this).attr("class") == ".AR_" + year) ` instead of ` if ($(this).attr("class") == "AR_" + year)`(the period infront of `AR`) might have had an impact.  Also in your filter version the filter is working on the parent `tr` rather than the `td`.  Hope that helps. R.

Comment: Yep, it sure does.  Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 1):

Should work, I see id `Td1` in your mark up but where is `[id^='AccessRequestID']`?

Comment: Whoops, that should be AccessRequestID.  Visual studio copy error.  Fixed it with the proper IDs now, thanks! :)

Comment: I would check your markup as it is rendered in the browser. The is probably a discrepancy somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that now...nothing's looking amiss there that I can see so far.